# Setting state with a function that returns an API call but my state returns a promise

Tags: reactjs, typescript, api

I have a separate function in a API.js file that makes an HTTP 'get' request to pull data back in the form of an array of objects. I've import this function into another React Component and have called the function to setState. When I console.log the value it returns a promise. I've also tried using async / await but I am not sure if it is playing nicely with typescript as the value of tableData then becomes undefined.

Ultimately, I am looking to pass the API data back into a table component and then render the data inside of the table but I either get back an empty object or undefined. Is there something I am missing?

Mainscreen.tsx Typescript Component

````
import { msalInstance } from '../auth/Auth';
//import AccountDetails from './AccountDetails';
import Form from "../components/Form/Form";
import { getTenantInfo } from "../API/API";
import Table from "./Table/Table";
import Footer from "./Footer/Footer";


class MainScreen extends React.Component {
    state = {
        userName: '',
        account: [],
        tableData: []
    }

    public componentDidMount(): void {
        const account: any = msalInstance.getAccount();
        const tableData =  getTenantInfo();
        console.log('tableData', tableData)
        this.setState({
            userName: account.userName, 
            account: account,
            tableData: tableData
        });
    }

    //     async componentDidMount()  {
    //     const account = await msalInstance.getAccount();
    //     const tableData = await  getTenantInfo();
    //     console.log('tableData', this.state.tableData)
    //     this.setState({
    //         userName: account.userName, 
    //         account: account,
    //         tableData: tableData
    //     });
    // }

    render(){
        
        return(
        <div className='App'>
            <Header style={{height:"100px"}}>
                <Logo />
                <p>Welcome {this.state.userName}!</p>
                <Button id="logout-btn" onClick = {() => {msalInstance.logout()}}>Logout</Button>
            </Header>
            
            
            <Form />
            <Table tableData={ this.state.tableData } />
            <Footer />
        </div>
        )
    }
}

export default MainScreen;```

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Table.js - React Component

    ```import React from "react";
    
    const Table = ({ tableData }) => {
      return (
        <div>
          <h1>Tenant Information</h1>
          <table>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Tenant</th>
                <th>Secrets Rotated</th>
                <th>Resident Token Rotation</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {console.log('tableData, null, 4' + JSON.stringify(tableData, null, 4))}
                { (tableData.length > 0) ? tableData.map( (data, index) => {
                    return (
                        <tr key={ index }>
                            {console.log('data' + data)}
                            <td></td>
                            <td>{ data[index].last_rotation }</td>
                            {/* <td>{ new Date() }</td>
                            <td>{ data.id }</td> */}
                        </tr>
                    )
    
                }) : <tr><td colSpan="5">Loading...</td></tr> }
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default Table;```
````

Comment: Also, Async / await is used in the function to make the API call in the other API folder - not shown above

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you also add the code that makes the relevant API call? If you're getting a Promise when you log the response, I suspect you're missing something in that API call.

Comment: is `msalInstance.getAccount()` also async?  or just `getTenantInfo()`

Comment: ```export async function getTenantInfo() {
    try {
        const res = await axios.get('<url>');
        return res.data;

    }
    catch (error) {
         return error.res.data;

    }

}```

Comment: msalinsatnce.getAccount() is not async but I could look to convert it to async

Comment: I get the data back properly when I call the API function in my other file. So I suspect it is something with setting the state in my mainscreen.tsx

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with an asynchronous call, we want to wait for the data to be received and then call `setState` to save it.  If `msalInstance.getAccount()` and `getTenantInfo()` are both `async` then we want to handle the them independently rather than setting state for both together.  Each one should be able to store its state as soon as it resolves.

You have set default initial values in your state of empty arrays and empty strings, so there shouldn't be any errors from trying to render before the promises have finished.

You can use either `async/await` or `promise/then` syntax.  It's just a syntactical difference and it's a promise behind the scenes either way, but the newer `async/await` syntax is generally preferred.

I'm putting the two actions into separate methods which we will then call from `componentDidMount`.

```
class MainScreen extends React.Component {
  state = {
    userName: '',
    account: [],
    tableData: []
  }

  public componentDidMount(): void {
    // initiates both actions at the same time, not in order
    this.loadAccount();
    this.loadTableData();
  }

  private async loadTableData() {
    const tableData = await getTenantInfo();
    console.log('tableData', tableData)
    this.setState({
      tableData
    });
  }

  private async loadAccount() {
    const account: any = await msalInstance.getAccount(); // fix this any!
    this.setState({
      userName: account.userName,
      account: account,
    });
  }

  render() {
     /*...*/
  }
}
```